# Change models.AutoField(primary_key=True) to Hexadecimal

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I am using django with `mongodb` using the `djongo` ORM.

I am facing a problem. I want to set `id` to be the autofield and according to django `AutoField` is of `IntegerField` type. But when it is inserted in `mongodb`, `mongodb` uses its conventional 12byte hexadecimal value.

This is the problem why I cannot edit in django admin, because `AutoField` is integer but in `mongodb` it becomes hexadecimal.

I want to create a custom `AutoField` which will be hexadecimal so as to solve my problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: @Baksteen I am trying to create one custom autofield. But by reading the documentations I am finding it a little difficult. And also I havent found any other helpful material for this.